# How to set data of first ListView in another ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Can anyone help me to solve my problem. I am new in android. I have a ListView which is show a list of data. And i want to do that user can select item from that ListView and that data will set in another ListView. I don't know how to do it because i'm totally new to android. Please help me.Thank you.

Comment: Show the codes you tried.

Comment: anything you have tried so far ??

Comment: No i doesn't try any code because i don't know how to do it.

Comment: do you know how to set a single listview ?

Comment: yes i know how to set single ListView but i don't know that how to set any ListView's selected data in another ListView.

Comment: read about listview.onItemClickListener

Comment: OK thanks. i'll try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ListView#onItemClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to achive this. Implement the `onItemClickListener` for first `ListView` to populate `ArrayAdapter` of the second `ListView`. Something like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    firstListView.setOnItemClickListener(new Android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Add new items based on clicked position to your second ListView
        })
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is helpful for me.